# Python pickle FileNotFound for specific name

Tags: python-3.x, exception, pickle

I have an strange problem trying to save a pickle using Python 3.7.4 on Windows 10. When I use a specific name starting with 'aux', it throws a FileNotFoundError. If I change the name it works great:

```
import pickle

list_example = [1, 2, 3]

# normal string - breaks
pickle.dump(list_example, open('aux.pk', 'wb'))

# trying raw string - breaks
pickle.dump(list_example, open(r'aux.pk', 'wb'))

# trying formatted string - breaks
file_name = 'aux'
pickle.dump(list_example, open(f'{file_name}.pk', 'wb'))

# trying other extension - breaks
pickle.dump(list_example, open('aux.foo', 'wb'))

# changing name, it works
pickle.dump(list_example, open('tux.pk', 'wb'))
pickle.dump(list_example, open('tux.foo', 'wb'))
```

I know I can change the name and make it works But, just for the curiosity, does anyone know why it happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because on windows file name `aux` is invalid. Following are also reserved:

```
CON
PRN
AUX
NUL
COM1, COM2, COM3, COM4, COM5, COM6, COM7, COM8, COM9, COM0
LPT1, LPT2, LPT3, LPT4, LPT5, LPT6, LPT7, LPT8, LPT9, LPT0
```

Reference: https://kizu514.com/blog/forbidden-file-names-on-windows-10/

Comment: Thanks a lot! I have to admit the extension FileNotFoundError didn't help on this one.

Comment: yeah, i had ran into the same trouble as when saving a file i wanted to call `auxiliary` and used `aux` :). Please accept as final answer :)